# Для чего нужен var перед переменными в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать `JS`, непонимаю для чего нужен `var` перед переменными если все хорошо работает и без этого.

Чем отличается `var x = 12;` от `x = 12;` ??

Comment: без указания var переменная создается в глобальной области видимости

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, она и с var там периодически создается :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var переменные видны внутри функций `function`
Когда объвляете переменную без `const` `let` или `var`, они становятся видны в глобальной области видимости

```js
function myFuncNoVar() {
  x = 5;
}

myFuncNoVar();
console.log(x);

function myFuncYesVar() {
  var y = 5;
}

myFuncYesVar();
console.log(y);
```

Comment: А, понял! Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: а разве, если ты объявишь с `var`  без функции - переменная не станет видна в глобальной области?

Comment: @Grundy если объявлю переменную с `var` `let` или `const` в глобальной области видимости, то она станет видна в глобальной области видимости

Comment: судя по ответу - нет